# incorrect file type '/tmp/#sql_53b8_0.MYI'; try to repair it

Tags: mysql

when i  tried to run the query,but found the following issue

```
 **Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_53b8_0.MYI'; try to repair it**
```

following is query ,should i need to optimize more.

> SELECT A.id, A.user_id, A.trans_id, A.work_order_id, A.total_ammount,
>   A.work_order_status, B.first_name, B.last_name,
>   DATE_FORMAT(transaction_date,'%d-%m-%Y') AS transaction_date1,
>   o.status as tstatus, os.status as act_status FROM tbl_order A LEFT
>   JOIN tech_order o ON A.id = o.orderId LEFT JOIN tech_orderstatus os ON
>   o.orderId = os.orderId AND o.technicianID = os.techid, tbl_user B
>   WHERE A.user_id=B.id AND A.transaction_date between '2016-11-08' AND
>   '2016-11-08' AND os.status='closed'OR order_status='closed' OR
>   o.status='closed' ORDER BY transaction_date ASC

Comment: Please fix your formatting.  By the way, your error message may have nothing to do with the query.

Comment: @tim thanks i will fallow your suggestion, but would you please tell me how to fix this issue

Comment: There are many other stack overflow posts with this same issue. Please see the answers listed in them.

Comment: respected  @tim, i am waiting for reply , hope you have better solution

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a large join and are running out of space on the disk for your temporary table. There are a few things you can do.

See solutions here:

[MySQL: Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_185e_0.MYI'; try to repair it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019799/mysql-incorrect-key-file-for-table-tmp-sql-185e-0-myi-try-to-repair-it?rq=1)

[Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_3c51_0.MYI'; try to repair it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11805793/incorrect-key-file-for-table-tmp-sql-3c51-0-myi-try-to-repair-it?rq=1)

[How do you fix a MySQL "Incorrect key file" error when you can't repair the table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428738/how-do-you-fix-a-mysql-incorrect-key-file-error-when-you-cant-repair-the-tabl)

Also, you likely could have found the other stack overflow posts with this in it by searching "mysql incorrect key file type try to repair it"